# Suppose $A$ is a $2x2$ matrix and ${\bf x}=(x_1, x_2)$. What does "$f(Ax)$ is supermodular" mean?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, optimization, real-analysis

Suppose $A$ is a $2x2$ matrix, e.g., $A=\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}  \\
a_{21} & a_{22}  \\
\end{vmatrix}$, and ${\bf x}=(x_1, x_2)$. Suppose $f()$ is continuous and twice differentiable.

What does "$f(Ax)$ is supermodular" mean?

For example, if $f(x)$ is supermodular, we have the cross partials of $f()$ with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$ nonnegative.

How can we similarly represent $f(Ax)$ supermodular in terms of the second partial and cross partial derivatives?

Note: I am interested in the expression for the continuous case and not the general lattice definition if possible.

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:
$$
f(Ax) = f(a_{11} x_1 + a_{12} x_2, a_{21} x_1 + a_{22} x_2).
$$
So the derivative with respect to $x_1$ is given by:
$$
f_1 a_{11} + f_{2} a_{21}.
$$
Taking the derivative of this with respect to $x_2$ gives:
$$
f_{11} a_{11} a_{12} + f_{12} a_{11} a_{22} + f_{21} a_{21} a_{12} + f_{22} a_{21} a_{22}.
$$
Supermodularity means that this is non-negative. So:
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^2 \sum_{j = 1}^2 f_{ij} a_{i1} a_{j2} \ge 0 = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{21}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} f_{11} & f_{12} \\ f_{21} & f_{22} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_{12} \\ a_{22} \end{bmatrix}.
$$